# How to call JavaScript/jQuery function from .cs file (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net (C#) project which include some page files (aspx, aspx.cs) and some only (.cs) file. I'm able to access JavaScript/jQuery functions from page files (aspx, aspx.cs) using `scriptregister`, but my question is how to access the JavaScript/jQuery function from alone (.cs) file. I'm generating some html tags in (.cs) file therefore in need of to call JavaScript/jQuery functions from only (.cs) class.

The file I have are, for example, `Default.aspx` and `Default.aspx.cs` and `Web.cs` (My concern is to call JavaScript/jQuery functions from web.cs)

Actually, What I'm trying to do is to generate some HTML code in Web.cs (Business Object) and while generating HTML code in web.cs I need some other dynamic HTML code generated by jQuery function which output is my concern: `var output ="My HTML Code Generated by jQuery function"`

Now I need the above jQuery output to merger with Web.cs HTML code generating.

Kindly let me know how can it be possible to call jQuery functions from web.cs and get back the result from jQuery to web.cs in order to merge?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call JavaScript/jQuery function from .cs file C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762441/how-to-call-javascript-jquery-function-from-cs-file-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

you can try to write to a response stream directly and output

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> your JS call</script>");
```

Regards,
Szymon

Answer (score 2):

You can call a JavaScript function using `registerStartupScript`.

ASPX Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function printOutput(arg) {            
      alert(arg);
   }

</script>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void DoSomethingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

   cs.RegisterStartupScript(typeof (Page), "PrintScript_" + UniqueID, "printOutput('My HTML Code Generated by jquery function');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass into the web.cs a reference to the page.  You will then have access to the page.clientscript method