# How can i find extra closing div in html string

Tags: asp.net, html

I have some html stored in **database**.
I dont know that html stored in databse has extra closing **div** like `</div>` or not.
I want to find extra closing div in html string.
I have tried to find using **HTML Agility** pack but not find the way to achieve this.
Example:

```
<div class="readers">
    A total of 218 users are reading this article.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can i find these two extra closing **div** and extract fully valid html.

Comment: Have you tried [w3 HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) ?

Comment: An off-the-shelf HTML parser should be able to highlight problems such as extra ending tags.  Are you looking specifically for extra ending div tags, or for _any_ syntax problems?

Comment: Do you just want to find the extra </div>s? Or do you want to just fix the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pure javascript parser before rendering the html: http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

You can check out by pasting your code here,
http://ejohn.org/apps/htmlparser/
it removes the extra `</div>`s.

You just need to pass your html to the `HTMLtoXML` function as:

```
HTMLtoXML(your_html);
```

and it would remove the extra closing tags. Infact what it does is that it converts it into xml format, but since you are dealing with html strigs & all tags are expected to be valid in html, you can be safe to use this.

**EDIT:** You can easily call javascript functions from a C# file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775606/how-to-call-javascript-jquery-function-from-cs-file-c) question for more details.

Comment: Hi Gopi, I like this but i am fetching html in .cs file.
So i want html parser that can work in .cs file.

Comment: @user1221708 there are many methods to call a javascript function from a C# file. See this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775606/how-to-call-javascript-jquery-function-from-cs-file-c

Comment: Hi Gopi, But i have to extract valid html in cs file and need to do some other operation. please help if you have other idea to extract valid html. Thanks for last response.

Comment: dont have much idea about that, but try googling for asp.net html parser, gives some useful results..

Answer (score -1):

Click here to find both unclosed (hanging) as well as extra div tags: [tormus](http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker)